# How to get the size of a UICollectionView cell before rotation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, orientation-changes

I have a UICollectionView that has a width that is a percentage of it's parent. When it rotates I need to know what the size it is going to be, so I can invalidate the layout and redraw the collection view cells to be the new full width. I was using viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: method, but the size it returns is of the entire screen. Is there any easy way to get the new frame of a UICollectionView before the orientation change takes effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
          super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator) 

          print(self.collectionView.frame) // old frame
          coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

           }) { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
              print(self.collectionView.frame) // new frame
           }


    }
```